# If $X = Y$ with probability $p$ and $X=Z$ with probability $1-p$, then $E[X] = p E[Y] + (1-p)E[Z]$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a random variable $X$.

With probability $p$, $X = Y$
and with probability $1-p$, $X = Z$

where $Y$ and $Z$ are both random variables. Is this above and below formulations problematic?

Can I argue that

$$E[X] = p E[Y] + (1-p)E[Z]$$

?

Comment: There are some ambiguities and problems. For example, are $X = Y$ and $X = Z$ mutually exclusive events? Also, the values of $Y$ even on the set where $X \not = Y$ will affect $E[Y]$, but not $E[X]$.

Comment: @AreaMan If I understood the problem correctly, it is implied that $X$ has one distribution with probability $p$ and another one with probability $1-p$.

Comment: @Ramil : yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: If you are talking about the conditional distributions then it is fine. That is not what you wrote.

Comment: I'm being pedantic because you asked for problems with your formulation...

Comment: @AreaMan Please replace "pedantic" by "precise". Let me state a simple counterexample to the question currently asked: consider $(Y,Z)$ uniform on $[0,1]^2$ and $X=\max(Y,Z)$. Then $E(X)\ne\frac12E(Y)+\frac12E(Z)$ although $P(X=Y)=P(X=Z)=\frac12$.

Comment: +1 to what @Did wrote. Moreover, even the events being mutually exclusive does not help. Say, for a standard Gaussian $X$, $X = \max(X,0)$ with probability $1/2$, $X = -|X|$ with probability $1/2$, and these events are mutually exclusive (except some negligible set). However, $E[X]\neq \frac 12 (E[\max(X,0)]-E[|X|])$.

Comment: @zhoraster Nice example.

Comment: @Did Precise is a better word, agreed. We do have a fairly universal standard of precision in mathematics, so it's not pedantry to complain if someone doesn't use it. Thanks for sharing the illuminating example.For others reading, I suggest drawing a picture of Did's example with sample space $[0,1]^2$. Then the reason for the non-equality can be understood geometrically / intuitively, with minimal computation.

Comment: Agreed. The question is rather problematic from my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below it is assumed that $X=Y$ and $Y = Z$ are disjoint events that are independent on the values of $Y$ and $Z$ and form partitions of the probability space, and $p = P(X=Y) \in (0, 1)$.

Then the formula in question is true, because of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). In this case, we obtain:

$$E[X] = E[X | X=Y]P(X=Y) + E[X | X=Z]P(X=Z) = pE(Y) + (1-p)E[Z]$$

Comment: There is nothing in the assumption that says ${X = Y}$ and ${X = Z}$ are a partition of the sample space. Also, $E[X | X = Y] \not = E[Y]$ in general, since values of the former do not depend on the values of $Y$ outside $\{X = Y\}$. (presumably by the former you mean the expectation of the restriction of $X$ to the set $\{X= Y\}$, with normalized probability measure...) At least, I claim all of this. Am I terribly confused?

Comment: @AreaMan Exactly one of these two events happens: $X = Y$ or $X=Z$, therefore the first equality should be correct (the law of total expectation is applicable here). As regards to the second one, it also seems to be true, because $p(X=x | X=Y) = p(Y=x)$ -- i.e. $(X | X=Y)$ has the same distribution as $Y$.

Comment: Let $\Omega = \{0,1,2\}$ Set $X(x) = x$ and $Y(0) = 0$, $Y(1) = 0$, $Y(2) = 1$. Then $P(X = 0 | X = Y) = 1$, $P(Y = 0) = 2/3$.

Comment: @AreeMan What is $P(X=0|X=Y)$ in this case?
$$P(X=0|X=Y) = \dfrac{P(X=Y=0)}{P(X=Y)}$$
But $P(X=Y) = 0$, so the conditional probability is not properly defined in this case.

Comment: @AreaMan I added explicitly that it was assumed that $X=Y$ and $Y=Z$ are disjoint events with positive probabilities, thanks.

Comment: No, $P(X = Y) = 1/3$, it happens at $0$.

Comment: @AreaMan sure, yes, thanks. I suppose, the event $X=Y$ should be independent with $Y$.

Comment: @AreaMan I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it is getting overly complicated, and I'm not convinced that independence is really the right condition here. The confusion is that HTV said equality of random variables, but really distributed like was meant.